# Можно ли в консоли заменить написанную строку?

Tags: c#, консоль, строки

То есть если уже написал, например, а = 25, как при следующей итерации заменить/обновить значение, не добавляя новую строку?

Comment: Может, возврат каретки без перевода строки?

Comment: Другими словами, Вас интересует, есть ли в `C#` аналог `GNU Readline library`?

Comment: Ну, вот вывел в окно консоли через Console.WriteLine значение некой переменной, допустим, int price = 50. Сейчас в окне красуется "Цена: 50 руб".   
Затем значение изменилось и составило price = 55.  

И вот тут мне необходимо не выводить новую строку в консоль, а заменить предыдущую, то есть чтобы во время выполнения программы текст не шел вниз, а стоял на месте, меняя лишь значение в самой первой строке.  

Можно использовать .Clear(), но он всю консоль очищает.

Comment: Так Вы хотите выводить (рисовать) символы в произвольном месте экрана или редактировать введенный ранее текст?

Comment: @avp, редактировать введенный ранее текст.

Comment: @julie, сама по себе консоль в плане взаимодействия с пользователем инструмент, как понимаете, нехитрый. А потому делать с ней можно немногое (ценой небольших усилий во всяком случае). При необходимости можно с помощью нехитрых колдунств очищать конкретную строку (скажем, на stackoverflow есть немало рецептов), но все же если есть необходимость в сколько-нибудь сложном зваимодействии, то, наверное, лучше писать приложение с более дружественным, нежели консоль, интерфейсом.

Comment: @julie,

если в в конце строки не сделан переход на новую строку, то можно вывести на терминал символ '\r', который заставит перейти в начало текущей строки. После этого можно снова выводить текст - он перетрет существующий. Конечно, нужно не забыть пробелами закрыть хвост.

Если хочется немного больше, можно использовать библиотеку [ncurses](http://curses-sharp.sourceforge.net/) - она портирована по С#.

@DreamChild, исправьте ошибку - s/более/менее/ :)

Answer (score 2):

Можно. 
В C# это делать очень просто.
Используя класс [Console](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.console(v=vs.110).aspx).
Посмотрите его методы и свойства, там можно устанавливать текущую позицию курсора, очищать консоль, получать координаты курсора.